# Insert new Value in MySQL in same Cloumn (Java/Code)

Tags: java, mysql

I am working on a little project.
Now I don't know, how to "replace" a old value in the mysql table.
Here you can see the table:

[image: So should it be always in PhPMyAdmin]

Thats my methods:

```
 MySQL.update("INSERT INTO OnlineServer (Name) VALUES ('" + API.getServerFreeServer() + "');");


 public static void update(String qry) {
    try {
        java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(qry);
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        connect();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem now is, if I update the mysql, it dont replace the value in the column "Name". It just add a new Value under the old Value. The table is Going to be too huge if I Update every 5 seconds.

I need exactly one value in the column "Name".
So I have tryed to replace the insert but it doesn't work for me.

Maybe you have some ideas?
Sorry for my bad English, I'am German.

Comment: you can try and inser into tbl(a, b, c) values (a, b, c) ; then update tbl set c=d where a=a and b=b; the key part is there where in the update

Comment: You could try using `UPDATE` or `MERGE`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do an *update* here of the table, rather than an insert:

```
String sql = "UPDATE OnlineServer Set Name = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, API.getServerFreeServer());
ps.executeUpdate();
```

By the way, your current query is doing raw string concatenation, making it prone to typos as well as SQL injection.  I have used a prepared statement above, which is the most desirable way to execute a query using JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` operation is for adding new record only and thus irrespective of you specify single column or 1million column it will add a new record. You actually need an `UPDATE` statement saying

```
UPDTE OnlineServer SET Name = <value>
```

You might also want to check [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)